# Cron can't execute a shell functioning PHP

Tags: php, cron, exec

I'm backing my databases each night with cron.

The files I run is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?

mkdir($date('Y-m-d'), 0700);

$user = 'root';
$pass = 'mypassword';
$host = 'localhost';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $user, $pass);

$dbs = $dbh->query('
    SELECT `schema_name` 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA  
');

while(($db = $dbs->fetchColumn(0)) !== false) {
    exec('mysqldump --user='.$user.' --password='.$pass.' --host='.$host.' '.$db.' > '.$db.'.sql');
}

?>
```

Everything's works fine when I execute the file in the browser.

When the file is executed by cron, it juste create the directory but does not create the sql backup files.

Do you know why ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have a different php.ini for the cli. Make sure it can exec.

Comment: @TimMorton, yes it allows the execution of `exec`. `disable_functions` is actually empty.

Comment: Are you sure you’re connecting to the database? It could be silently failing the `while`. Or silently erroring out, for that matter

Comment: @TimMorton, yes as I explain it's working well in the browser.

Comment: Just because it works on one platform doesn’t mean it works flawlessly on another. I’m not saying your code is bad, but there’s obviously something different in the configuration or the connection to the database.  Before you assume that you’re getting data back from the database, take the time to *prove* it to yourself

Comment: @TimMorton, just made the following test. Run `mkdir` right after the `exec` where the directory name is the database name. It worked.

Comment: Well, now you know it is the line with the exec statement. Can the user php is running under run mysqldump?

Comment: @TimMorton, how can I check this please?

Comment: I’m a bit rusty on Linux, but what you need to answer first is what user is running cron?  Does that user have permission to run mysqldump?  Sorry, you’re starting to go beyond where I can help